# error when adding a default page to web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have 1 webpage with a SQL connection. When I run on localhost on Windows 7, this error occurs.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Config Error Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'value' set to 'default.aspx'
>
> Config File \?\D:\SIPLWEB\WebSite\web.config

```
 120:             <files>
 121:                 <add value="default.aspx" />
 122:             </files>
```

Answer (score 4):

You already have "default.aspx"  as the default document at a higher level, most likely in your iis config, it's added by default. You can find it in your `applicationHost.config` file.

You can remove the default document entry from your `web.config` file and it will work.